# Rewriting linq query based on column check and corrupted data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a table which has structure like below :

```
JobListings:

JobID
CompanyID
Status 
ActiveDate
ExpiryDate
CreationDate
```

Now I want to calculate below statistics based on conditions:

```
Active
OnHold
Closed
Filled
Expired
```

Now because of some data corruption, I had a problem in `ActiveDate` field which contains date like this for some jobs : **"0001-01-01"**

> So what I want to do is if ActiveDate has data like "0001-01-01" then
> Consider ExpiryDate column else consider ActiveDate only.

I am trying to retrieve this statistics for the first day of month till today.

Here is my query:

```
var statistics = (from j in context.Job
                        where j.CompanyID == 100 &&
                        (j.ActiveDate == "0001-01-01" ? (j.CreationDate >= fromDate && j.CreationDate <= toDate):
                        (j.ActiveDate >= fromDate && j.fromDate <= today))
                        group j by j.Status into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = g.Key,
                            Statistics = g.Count()
                        });
```

Is there a better way to rewrite this query?

Comment: Looks good. Only small copy/paste mistake `(j.ActiveDate >= fromDate && j.fromDate <= today)` - should be corrected to `(j.ActiveDate >= fromDate && j.ActiveDate <= today)`

Comment: Why not update the base table first to remove/update the erroneous data, rather than make your queries jump through hoops to correct it over and over again? One `UPDATE` should do it. Even if updating is out of the question for some reason, a view that encodes this logic would save duplicating it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah agree with you. In case if I want to calculate this statistics for past 6 months and I want to calculate month wise statistics like Jan - 10, Feb - 20 etc.... Then any thoughts on this? because in group by again I will be having condition right so I am little confused

Comment: It looks like you fall back on treating `CreationDate` as the `ActiveDate` if there is no (valid)`ActiveDate`, so wouldn't a simple `UPDATE JobListings SET ActiveDate = CreationDate WHERE ActiveDate = '00010101'` do? The question of how to do the grouping seems to be an entirely separate one, but that too will be easier if you only have `ActiveDate` to consider.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah but actually I cant do that as I dont have control over Database. Thats the problem, I have to include this check